# For each possible permutation of factor levels, apply function and also name list of results

Tags: r, permutation, apply, categorical-data, levels

**Improve the following code by rewriting to be more compact (a one-liner with alply or similar?)** Also if it can be made more performant (if possible).

I have a dataframe with several categorical variables, each with various number of levels. (Examples: T1_V4: B,C,E,G,H,N,S,W and T1_V7: A,B,C,D )
For any specific one of those categorical vars, I want to do the following:

- Construct all possible level-permutations e.g. using `DescTools::Permn()`
- Then for each `level.perm` in those level.perms...
- Construct a list of function results where we apply some function to level.perm (in my particular case, recode the factor levels using level.perms, then take as.numeric, then compute correlation wrt some numeric response variable)
- Finally, name that list with the corresponding string-concatenated values of level.perm (e.g. 'DBCA')
- Example at bottom for permutations of A,B,C,D

Reproducible example at bottom:

The following code does this, can you improve on it? (I tried alply)

```
require(DescTools)

level.perms <- Permn(levels(MyFactorVariable))

tmp <- with(df,
  apply( level.perms, 1,
    function(var.levels) {
      cor(MyResponseVariable,
          as.numeric(factor(MyFactorVariable, levels=var.levels)))
  })
)
names(tmp) <- apply(level.perms, 1, paste, collapse='')
```

Example (for CategVar1 with levels A,B,C,D):

```
     ABCD      BACD      BCAD      ACBD      CABD      CBAD      BCDA      ACDB 
 0.031423  0.031237  0.002338  0.002116 -0.026496 -0.026386 -0.008743 -0.009104 
     CADB      CBDA      ABDC      BADC      CDAB      CDBA      ADBC      BDAC 
-0.037228 -0.037364  0.048423  0.048075 -0.048075 -0.048423  0.037364  0.037228 
     BDCA      ADCB      DABC      DBAC      DBCA      DACB      DCAB      DCBA 
 0.009104  0.008743  0.026386  0.026496 -0.002116 -0.002338 -0.031237 -0.031423
```

Reproducible example using randomly-generated dataframe:

```
set.seed(120)
df = data.frame(ResponseVar = exp(runif(1000, 0,4)),
       CategVar1 = factor(sample(c('A','B','C','D'), 1000, replace=T)),
       CategVar2 = factor(sample(c('B','C','E','G','H','N'), 1000, replace=T)) )
cor(as.numeric(df$CategVar1), df$MyResponseVar)
# 0.03142
cor(as.numeric(df$CategVar2), df$MyResponseVar)
# 0.02112
#then if you run the above code you get the above table of correlation values
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but your reproducible example has errors - the `cor` line throws errors (column is called `ResponseVar`), and your example code above doesn't work either on the example (`CategVar1` vs `MyFactorVariable`). Also, what do you mean by "improve" your code - is speed an issue? Or you just want a one-liner, even if it's slower? etc

Comment: You know, I reckon your code is pretty optimal (speed-wise)...

Comment: The variable names are obvious placeholders, fill in the right name. 'Improve' both compactness (one-liner?) ; also speed, since this runs in factorial-time, and gets slow for 8+ levels (I'll have to drop the less-frequent levels)

Comment: Algorithmically, do I only need to test whether each pair-wise swap of level order in the permutations gives an increase in correlation?

Comment: I'm not sure, what is the aim of your code? Is it simply to calculate correlation for all possible labellings of your factors, or is to find the labelling that gives the highest correlation? Also note that (e.g.) correlation with ABCD is -correlation of DCBA, so you only need to do half the permutations.

Comment: Yeah I had already noticed I only need to do the first half of the permutations, but that's minor and doesn't help with factorial-complexity. Yes the intent is to find the level permutation giving maximum correlation.

Comment: Ah. This makes a *huge* difference. I thought you were merely after more efficient ways to perform your above code (i.e. R question), not specifically searching for a combination giving maximum correlation (more of an optimisation/stats question).

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding this; the question is exactly as I wrote it, please revert your edit. I did ask you to improve the R code, both in **compactness** (***can you make it a one-liner with alply?*** - I'd still like to see that) and **performance**. Since your reaction is that the general R code is already pretty optimal, then further improvements could only come from algorithm-specific improvements. The only low-hanging fruit I see on this specific algorithmic complexity is to ignore rare levels. But as you say that's a different question. So can you do the alply part?